# space between beamercolorbox in headline

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to create a horizontal headline box consisting of two different colors. This is what I have right now:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\definecolor{accent1}{RGB}{0, 110, 220} %blue
\definecolor{accent2}{RGB}{255, 248, 220} %cornsilk 

\setbeamercolor{accent12}{fg=accent1,bg=accent2}
\setbeamercolor{accent21}{fg=accent2,bg=accent1}

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{family=\rm}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
    \leavevmode
    \hbox
    {
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.5\paperwidth,ht=3ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{accent12}
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.5\paperwidth,ht=3ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{accent21}
            \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsectionhead
        \end{beamercolorbox}

    }
    \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty %remove navigation panel

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
    hello
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

there are a few problems with this code.

1. As you can see in the output there is a small space between the two color boxes, but why? Both boxes are set to a width of `0.5\paperwidth`?
2. There are overfull hbox warnings, why and how to get rid of them?

Comment: You have removed the `%` from my answer, that's what causes the small space. And the overfull hbox is logical for a line that's longer than 2*0.5*`\paperwidth`.

Comment: @TeXnician I remember me taking this code a long time ago from your answer, but I also remember there were many `%`, which specific `%` are needed to get rid of the error? (Also, I never thought removing comment marks could make a code go from working to not working as intended...)

Comment: Those which were in there (between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`) are needed. What those do is essentially preventing TeX from inserting a space (at least that's the effect).

Comment: @TeXnician cool thanks, that works. I noticed that if I remove the hbox, I don't need the comment marks anymore... so is it only in the specific case that when one combines beamercolorboxes and hbox(`\leavevmode` and `\hbox`) or are there other things I should watch out for?

Comment: There are many cases you do actually need those comment marks, but you can read it up on this page (just search for it). Please have a look at that.